# How do i display client's ip address in the report using c socket program?

Tags: c

I server report need to display the clients ip address in the report which is processed by the server,that is i need to display from which client the report is being sent. How do i do this? Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this :

```
char clntName[INET6_ADDRSTRLEN];
char portName[6]; 

if (getnameinfo(&client_address,
                sizeof client_address,
                clntName,
                sizeof(clntName),
                NULL,
                0,
                NI_NUMERICHOST|NI_NUMERICSERV|NI_NUMERICSCOPE) == 0) {
    printf("Client = %s/%s\n",clntName,portName);
} else {
    printf("Unable to get address\n");
}
```

Comment: printf() + uninitialized portName char array may cause a crash. Or at least printf() outputs some trash.

Answer (score 0):

The 'remoteIp' char array in following code will give you the client's ip address, whcih you can print using string functions. 'fd' is the listen socket for your server port..

```
struct sockaddr_in remoteAddr;
int size = sizeof(remoteAddr);
char remoteIp[10] = {0};
acceptFd = accept(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&remoteAddr, &size);
inet_ntop(AF_INET, &remoteAddr.sin_addr, remoteIp, INET_ADDRSTRLEN)
```